# How to decode websocket message in fiddler?

Tags: https, websocket, fiddler, spring-websocket, network-traffic

I record websockets using Fiddler, but messages a encoded.
I've attached a screenshot with the example of message to this question.

If there any workaround how to decode it?

Thank you for attention.

[image: ws message]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FiddlerScript: Put the following code in OnBeforeRequest function

```
if (oSession.RequestHeaders.ExistsAndContains ("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate")) {
oSession.RequestHeaders.Remove ( "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions");
}
```

This problem is caused by header `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate`

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/zXiHPOprR5s